# Behavior with Class and Method Variables with the same names

Tags: c#

Earlier I had an issue where I discovered some weird behavior with C#.

This will throw an error:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {
           for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
           {
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

But this will not:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, when for loop ends, x will be set back to 0. This will also work if you have one `int x` and one `bool x`.

Why does this work?

Comment: scope. The same reason why having a method parameter named the same as a class variable will take precedence over the class variable unless you use `this`

Comment: Your second example public int x is field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case you are defining the same variable within the same scope, twice, which is an error.

In the second case, you are defining a local variable within the scope of the loop, which will hide the class member `x` within that scope. Outside that scope, x will refer to the class member, but inside it will refer to the loop iteration variable.

Comment: Doesn't the for loop in the first example also define an inner scope though?  If you declare a variable inside the for loop you can't access it outside the for loop.

Comment: "A local variable named 'member' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'member', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"  - So isn't the class scope the parent scope of the function?

Comment: "The local variable declaration space of a block includes any nested blocks. Thus, within a nested block it is not possible to declare a local variable with the same name as a local variable in an enclosing block." -- CLS 3.3, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691107(v=vs.71).aspx